# How to check that which item is selected currently in Flip view in XAML C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, flipview

How can i check that which item of the flipview is currently selected and i want different action in code behind.

#### For Example

here is the code

```
<FlipView SelectionChanged="FlipView_SelectionChanged">
      <Stackpanel Name="sp1">
        // Stack panel 1
      </Stackpanel>
      <Stackpanel Name="sp2">
        // Stack panel 2
      </Stackpanel>
 </FlipView>
```

My question is how i know that "sp1" is selected currently or "sp2" is selected in code behing? any event or other method? or **in other words who can i know that user flipped from one view to the next view** 

Any response will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Give the FlipView a Name then you can reference the SelectedItem

**XAML**

---

```XAML
<FlipView Name="myFlipView" SelectionChanged="FlipView_SelectionChanged">
      <Stackpanel Name="sp1">
        // Stack panel 1
      </Stackpanel>
      <Stackpanel Name="sp2">
        // Stack panel 2
      </Stackpanel>
 </FlipView>
```

**C#**

---

```C#
// get selected index/item
StackPanel sp = (StackPanel) myFlipView.SelectedItem;
int selected_index = myFlipView.SelectedIndex;
string name_of_selected_panel = sp.Name;

// set selected index/item
myFlipView.SelectedIndex = 1;  // any valid index
myFlipView.SelectedItem = sp1;  // or any name of an item in the collection
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but how can i goto that index on some button click event?

Comment: You can do that the same way you retrieve it.  I will modify the sample code.